# Search suggestion not working in SharePoint 2016 search site?

Tags: search, 2016

In SharePoint 2016 search site search suggestion not working.

I tried HR or Benefits keyword search more than 6 times and then run Prepare query suggestions timer job multiple times but still while typing HR or benefits in search box not showing auto/search suggestion.

Any thing missing?

Comment: did you change the query suggestion minimum number of characters in the search box web part properties?

Comment: Search suggestion is ON right? Also ensure that it will take at least 15-30 mins to update. this will work

Comment: Search suggestion is ON at Search service application level and web part level and all are default settings. Query suggestion minimum number of characters is by default 2.

Comment: Did you check after sometime? Was it working? This is something weird. It should work perfectly.